# Outlook VBA - Using PickFolder to copy to PST

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

A user has some VBA code that pops up with a folder view to choose where to save a copy of "Sent Items" to when "Send" is pressed.

The issue is, it only works with the main mailbox, and not PST's

Is there a way to allow this code to copy to PST folders too?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
        If Not objFolder Is Nothing And _
          IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) And _
          objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder

            Set msg = MailItem.Copy
            msg.UnRead = False

            msg.Save

            msg.Move objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
        Else
            Set objFolder = _
              objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder

            Set msg = MailItem.Copy
            msg.UnRead = False

            msg.Save

            msg.Move objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
        End If
    End If
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
Public Function IsInDefaultStore(objOL As Object) As Boolean
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim blnBadObject As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objApp = objOL.Application
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set objNS = objApp.Session
        Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Select Case objOL.Class
            Case olFolder
                If objOL.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case olAppointment, olContact, olDistributionList, _
                 olJournal, olMail, olNote, olPost, olTask
                If objOL.Parent.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case Else
                blnBadObject = True
        End Select
    Else
        blnBadObject = True
    End If
    If blnBadObject Then
        MsgBox "This function isn't designed to work " & _
                "with " & TypeName(objOL) & _
                " objects and will return False.", _
                , "IsInDefaultStore"
        IsInDefaultStore = False
    End If
    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the messages moved to somewhere other than the default Sent Items folder?  If so, you either need to ask the user to pick it or get a Folder object via NameSpace.GetFolderFromID if you have saved the Folder.EntryID value for the destination folder somewhere.  Otherwise, you'll have to find the folder by name by looping through Store.Folders for every Store in NameSpace.Stores, which could get nasty.

Comment: Yes I have already done this as per the code above. The issue is that when selecting a PST folder, it doesn't save it at all.

Comment: Is the pst folder in your default store? According to your logic it'll use the default Sent Items folder if the folder you pick isn't.